# Word search that looks for words mentioned in YouTube Videos

Tags: java, list, intellij-idea, set, youtube-data-api

I am trying to  implement a trending topic analyser for the list of videos. This amounts to indexing the word usage across the title and description of the. Also to note and mention, I am wanting it where all punctuation symbols are
included in the “word”, “twinkle,” is NOT the same as “twinkle” and counts multiple occurrences of a word in a title and description.

The application I am developing is basically based on a command line application that can detect the YouTube Trending Topics on Intelli j java.

I have some code that is sort of something I have created but am not sure how I would implement or do this for my application.

Here is the following code:

```
SomeCollection words (this could be a set, list, map, etc)
for each video
 for each word in video(title and description)
 if (word is in words)
 increment count for word in words
 else
 add word to words and set count to 1
 end
 associate video with word
 end
end
```

I understand you need classes from the Collections framework such as Lists, Maps and Sets to implement an algorithm like this but am not so sure in how to do this. Would I be able to get some help in doing this?

Comment: `SomeCollection words` Is this a fixed list of words? Or can it change during progra execution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all title of question is somewhat different then content, **word search** is something different then finding **trending topics**
If it is trending topic analyzer,

What i get is you need to implement something sort of search engine but without forward index.

A general outlook would be that you first concatenate title and description and split that huge string (to get words) and do this for each video, then remove all the **stop words** (words like a, the, was etc), you can easily find all the stop words list then you have to do what we call finding the **root word** for each word, this is the word which you will be storing in map (or list or whatever-although map is one of best options)-this step is achieved by **stemming** and **lemmatization**, and you could find lots of libraries for automating these tasks. This was initial word processing, now come to the goal.

You make a list of all words(roots) which you get after initial word processing.

```
Now you should be having:
                     -> dictionary : (all the root words of your dataset) 
                        with probable datatype of list
                     -> freq_map : a map that maps word to its total 
                        frequency in dictionary.



  Iterate through all words in word dictionary
  if word not in freq_map:
                           add it in freq_map
                           add it in nested map, map_f ( show below )
                           if current video_id not in map_f:
                                                            add it in in map_f with 
                                                            freq in it
                           else:
                                 increment frequency

  else:
                           increment its frequency in freq_map
                           if current video_id not in map_f:
                                                            add it in in map_f with 
                                                            freq in it
                           else:
                                 increment frequency
```

After doing all this you will get inverted index, map_f shown below:

```
{ 
  'word1' : {
              {'video1_id':word_freq},{'video2_id':word_freq} 
            } ,
  'word2' : { 
              {'video1_id':word_freq},{'video2_id':word_freq}
            },
  .
  .
 }
```

You will be storing map_f in csv or JSON file (parsing JSON is easier) or you could use 
any object serialization method in Java.

```
Scenarios : 
        your trending topic has to be one word topic -> above approach suffice.
        topic could be multi word -> If you are not concerned about high accuracy then 
        still above method suffice.
```

If it's what was in your head then go ahead and have a read on this site:

http://www.ardendertat.com/2012/01/11/implementing-search-engines/

Hope it helps.

In case you want to keep words as they are in title and description, you simply do not use root finding step.
And if you want to keep occurence of word in title and description separate then simply in the third level of nesting in map use somthing like:

```
 'video1_id':{0:word_freq, 1:word_freq}
  0 and 1 being the flags for location of word in either title or description.
```